# Display the name instead of the value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using a dropdown that lists a data set.

I created a treeBoxValue variable to assign a predefined dropdown value. Thus, when I open the dropdown, the elements that contain the value of the variable treeBoxValue are checked.

My problem is that the presentation of these default values ​​should contain the name and not the value.

Can someone help me to show only the names and not the values?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1jrwg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Problem:** The dropdown shows the values ​​and not the name :(

[image: IMG]

When I open the dropdown, the values ​​change to the name. I intend to get the names right at the beginning.

**Note:** If the dropdown did not open, refresh only the preview page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
treeBoxValue = ["1", "2"];
```

to this:

```
treeBoxValue = [1, 2];
```

In your Books array the field `idBook` is numeric.

```
Books = [
    {
      idBook: 1,
      name: "name1"
    },
    {
      idBook: 2,
      name: "name2"
    },
    {
      idBook: 3,
      name: "name3"
    }
  ];
```